# NDSolve problem

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-difference-method

I am trying to solve numerically this differential equation

```
s := NDSolve[{y''[x] + ω[x]*y[x] - 1/(y[x])^3 == 0,  y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0.3}, y, {x, 0, 10}]
```

where `ω[x]` is a complicated function, given by:

```
ω[x]=E^(4 (1 + 1/3 Log[Sinh[0.0411881 x]] - (
   Cos[π/18] Log[(
     Sqrt[Cos[π/18]^2 + Sin[π/18]^2] + Sqrt[
      Cos[π/18]^2 + Sin[π/18]^2 + 
       0.00001 Sinh[0.0411881 x]^2])/(
     Sqrt[Cos[π/18]^2 + Sin[π/18]^2] - Sqrt[
      Cos[π/18]^2 + Sin[π/18]^2 + 
       0.00001 Sinh[0.0411881 x]^2])])/(
   6 Sqrt[Cos[π/18]^2 + Sin[π/18]^2])))
```

Since this function has a divergence in 0, Mathematica can't solve the equation above. 
It gives the following errors: 
    `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
     NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.`.

Can you suggest any other way I can find the numerical solution?

I tried to move the interval, starting from `x==0.001`, but the solution obtained doesn't appear to be the right one.

Thank you all

Comment: Is there any reason that you're not simplifying your expression for `ω[x]`?  Note that `Sqrt[Cos[π/18]^2 + Sin[π/18]^2] = 1.`

Answer (score 2):

It always pays to simplify your equations:

```
ω2[x_] = Simplify[ω[x]]

(* E^4 Sinh[0.0411881 x]^(4/3) (-((1 + Sqrt[1. + 0.00001 Sinh[0.0411881 x]^2])/(-1 + Sqrt[1. + 0.00001 Sinh[0.0411881 x]^2])))^(-(2/3) Cos[π/18]) *)
```

Since this function is *not* indeterminate as $x \to 0$, you can use it in your ODE without a problem:

```
s = NDSolve[{y''[x] + ω2[x]*y[x] - 1/(y[x])^3 == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0.3}, y, {x, 0, 10}]
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[y[x] /. s]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

As @zhk noted in [their answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152901/27813), the function $\omega(x)$ is complex as defined, and so the resulting `y[x]` is complex as well.  In the graph above, the real part of `y[x]` is in blue and the imaginary part is in yellow.  The imaginary part stays small for the range of $t$ in the above plot, but it starts to become comparable to the real part around $t = 30$ or so.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to write a set is `ω[x_] =` not `ω[x] =`

```
ω[x_] = 
 E^(4 (1 + 
      1/3 Log[Sinh[
         0.0411881 x]] - (Cos[π/
           18] Log[(Sqrt[Cos[π/18]^2 + Sin[π/18]^2] + 
             Sqrt[Cos[π/18]^2 + Sin[π/18]^2 + 
               0.00001 Sinh[0.0411881 x]^2])/(Sqrt[
              Cos[π/18]^2 + Sin[π/18]^2] - 
             Sqrt[Cos[π/18]^2 + Sin[π/18]^2 + 
               0.00001 Sinh[0.0411881 x]^2])])/(6 Sqrt[
          Cos[π/18]^2 + Sin[π/18]^2])))
```

Now, if you assign a random value to `x` to check `ω`,

```
ω[1]
```

> -1.16889*10^-6 - 2.18208*10^-6 I

the output shows that `ω` is complex. So, we need to use `Re@ω` if interested in real values only.

```
s = NDSolve[{y''[x] + Re@ω[x]*y[x] - 1/(y[x])^3 == 0, 
       y[10^-4] == 1, y'[10^-4] == 0.3}, y, {x, 10^-4, 10}]

Plot[y[x] /. s, {x, 10^-4, 10}]
```

[image]